# is there another way to make this ? I have tried 6 versions of code, I can not seem to get a result when I run it

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am very new to this.i am trying to make this assignment for the last 6 hours(:_(),this is the 7th version of code im trying,i have a input file with the names and grades(10 names of students along with 3 grades per student,i try to input it but i can not see any results until an error pops up, i seem to be struggling with assigning the grades and getting a mean from it. is there any other way i can do this??

i have tried to split the input into seperate students then try to make the program read the name and grade and at last an average

```
with open('grades1.txt') as f:
 content = [line.split() for line in f]

 keys = content[0]

 lst = list(zip([keys]*(len(content)-1), content[1:]))
  x = [zip(i[0], i[1]) for i in lst]
  z = [dict(i) for i in x]


  Name,grade1,grade2,grade3 = x.split()
   subjects = [float(name), float(grade1), float(grade2), 
   float(grade3)]
   sum = 0
    zero_count = 0
    for subject in subjects:
   sum += subject
  if subject is 0:
     zero_count +=
   print(i,  sum/(len(subjects)-zero_count)
```

nothing i try seems to work,
 i keep getting syntax errors etc. here is link to the assignment:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cu0q1.png\

input: 
Tom______    5 4 4.5
Dain ________6 7 7
Thorin ____8 8 3
Meriadoc ____1.0 2.3 4.5
Sam_________2.4 6.5 4.7
Gollem________________1.8 6.7 5.3
Frodo ________9.1 3.7 8.5
Gandalfe_____5.1 5.5 6.9
Peregrijn________3.0 8.5 3.1
Bruine____2.0 6.0 2.5

output:
Tom has an average grade of 
Dain has an average grade of x
Thorinhas an average grade of x
Meriadoc has an average grade ofx x
Sam  has an average grade of x
Gollem has an average grade of x
Frod has an average grade of x
Gandalf has an average grade of x
Peregrijn has an average grade of x
Bruine has an average grade of x
End of report

Comment: If you're getting errors, please provide the full traceback of the error, as that will help us to help you. It would also help to see a sample of the file and a sample of your desired output.

Comment: Please don't post images (or links to images). Copy and paste the input file and the desired output so if someone wants to run your code they can just copy the file data. Also, since indentation is very important in Python, please make sure the code here is indented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your code but here's a fairly simple way to do it. See comments for explanation:

```
with open('grades1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        # Split on underscore to get name and grades (filtering out empty strings)
        # Grades will be in one string, ex: "1.0 5.0 7.7"
        name, grades_string = filter(None, line.split('_'))
        # Split grades string on space and convert to each float
        grades = [float(x) for x in grades_string.split(' ')]
        # Calc average
        average = sum(grades) / len(grades)
        # Print results (TODO: formatting/rounding)
        print name + ' has an average grade of ' + str(average)
```